# What Happened to Typesafe Console for Akka/Play Monitoring?

Tags: sbt, akka, typesafe-console

All links for information on *Typesafe Console* (e.g. http://typesafe.com/platform/runtime/console) get redirected to *[Typesafe Activator](http://typesafe.com/activator)*, a project tutorial/templating tool (not a monitoring tool). I can't find any information or links on the Typesafe website on where to get *Typesafe Console*, or how *Typesafe Activator* fills the same role *Typesafe Console* did.

Attempts to use the `sbt-atmos` plugin for invoking *Typesafe Console* from SBT when using Akka 2.3.x also fail, with Akka support only up to 2.2.1 (see [`AtmosRun.scala`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-atmos/blob/master/akka/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/atmos/AtmosRun.scala)).

What happened to *Typesafe Console*? It seems to have mysteriously disappeared!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found this message at the top of the *Typesafe Console* [mailing list page](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/typesafe-console):

> Typesafe announces the End-Of-Life cycle for commercial support of the
>   Typesafe Console. This also means that the open source support on this
>   mailing list will stop from now on. As previously stated we will
>   release another version with Akka 2.3.0 support and this will be the
>   last and final release of the Typesafe Console.
>
> Typesafe does not have any future plans to build tools for production
>   monitoring, instead we have partnered closely with leading APM vendors
>   including AppDynamics, New Relic, Takipi and others to fulfill your
>   enterprise production monitoring needs. Typesafe's widely used
>   development tool, Activator will include new functionality - Activator
>   Inspect - that will evolve over time to offer more development-time
>   focused monitoring capabilities, enabling developers to build robust
>   applications faster and more effectively.
>
> We are dedicated to your success and believe we can better serve you
>   and our community by strengthening partnerships with vendors that
>   focus solely on this critical aspect rather than attempting to build
>   production monitoring capabilities ourselves.

Note: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:typesafe.com+%22typesafe+console%22) nor the [Typesafe website](http://www.typesafe.com/blog?query=%22typesafe+console%22) reveal any additional announcement. [Here's the announcement](http://typesafe.com/blog/activator-11-integrates-app-inspection-and-a-new-ui) on *Typesafe Activator* "Inspect". Which is also [end-of-life by now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625762/cant-inspect-in-typesafe-activator) (lol).

Comment: isn't "Inspect" EOL'ed? the tab is gone in Activator, though maybe now this is just folded into "Monitor" or not available outside of Typsafe Reactive Platform. Would be nice to have an updated answer since I'm finding akka monitoring to be very hard to configure...

Comment: Lightbend activator is also reaching EOL next month :(