# Can't Inspect in Typesafe Activator

Tags: akka, typesafe-activator

I am new to the use of typesafe-activator.
I installed it using homebrew on my Mac and tried out the hello-akka tutorial.

Following said tutorial, at the end there is a section about Inspecting the App, for monitoring actor status and other things.
Now I can't seem to find the option to inspect the app in my activator web client (as shown in the image below), while googling for the problem hasn't given me any results.

Now the question is: do I need to install some plugin or something, or the homebrew version of activator is missing some functionalities?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like they have decided to discontinue it:
https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/1067

Comment: If you want to get something similar, they are developing Reactive Monitoring (https://www.typesafe.com/blog/introducing-reactive-monitoring-v1-0-beta-reactive-platform) which you will be able to get as part of the Reactive Platform. The good news is that you can use reactive platform for free for development (contact sales for production). But I personally don't feel as comfortable with Typesafe after this move.

Comment: Looks like nothing free helping to debug an akka application.. nor a default implementation shipping all logs to a centralized location.  https://github.com/levkhomich/akka-tracing and http://kamon.io/documentation/kamon-akka/0.6.6/overview/ might come close.