# How to import AKKA with Java project in Typesafe Activator

Tags: java, maven, akka, typesafe-activator, typesafe-console

I have an application written in Java, using the AKKA framework for Java built with Maven. It is an application which needs to connect simultaneously to multiple devices.
Due to this, I want to be able to monitor the lifespan of actors and other information which represents the state of the system.

I tried to install Typesafe Activator, but the problem is that I can't import the project, receiving an error:

> no sbt project found

My goal is to use the TypeSafe Console, I tried searching but found nothing clear. Any help?

Comment: Activator's projects are setup using sbt as build tool, not maven. If your project is maven based, you can't import it into the activator. But, anyways, I'm unsure why you are doing this: if your goal is monitoring that has nothing to do with activator, activator is just a collection of sample projects

Comment: I need to use the Typesafe console

Comment: Yes, you have said that. What I'm asking you is what do you need to use the console for? I fear you might have a misconception of what the console and the activator are for. Also, note that the console is discontinued http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652401/what-happened-to-typesafe-console-for-akka-play-monitoring